# How to differentiate SCREEN_ON and PHONE_STATE broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen, phone-state-listener

I have two broadcast.

One is for screen on/off and second for phone state. I want to show my activity to user if screen is on but not if it is phone call.

How to manage this any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use if/else condition to identify Broadcast action as:

```
public static final String Screen_on = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(Screen_on)) {
   // do your job here if screen is on /off
}
else{
        // send new intent to your Activity here 
         Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity1.class);
     intent.putExtra("status","CALL_STATE");
     context.startActivity(intent);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) {
           // do your job here if PHONE STATE CHNAGED
        }
      }

}
```

and declare your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` as `android:launchMode="singleTask"`  and override onNewIntent to recive intent when Activity running as :

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    finishactivity();
}
private void finishactivity(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
          if(extras.getString("status").equals("CALL_STATE"))
         // finish your Activity here
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but seems a problem like screen_on is called first than Phone state, Suppose on screen_on I have shown my activity then after getting Phone_state receiver that activity should not be displayed.

Comment: @sandy : as your question this code start activity only when SCREEN_ON Action BroadcastReceiver .

Comment: @sandy :  see my edit answer maybe help you to achieve what u looking for